# Call update function when initializing a custom property

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I am writing an add-on with a panel UI, in which I want to have a drop-down list of all objects in a specified .blend file, so that my operator could append the selected object. I've managed to do that using a custom EnumProperty (`object_name`) and passing a callback function (`object_list_callback`) to dynamically update the items list (like in the [Property Definitions](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty)).

Since opening another .blend file and grabbing all objects names is relatively slow, I store the objects names in a custom CollectionProperty (`scene.my_object_list`), which I update only when I change the specified .blend file path (`file_path`), using the update function `file_path_update`.

```
def object_list_callback(self, context):
    items = [(obj.name, obj.name, '') for obj in context.scene.my_object_list]
    return items

def file_path_update(self, context):
    ''' Update the objects types list '''
    context.scene.my_object_list.clear()

    # Open the specified file
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(self.file_path) as (data_from, _):
        # Add all object names to the list
        for obj_name in data_from.objects:
            new_item = context.scene.my_object_list.add()
            new_item.name = obj_name

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    file_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = 'Objects File Path',
        subtype = 'FILE_PATH',
        update = file_path_update,
        default = "D:\\Data\\Objects_File.blend"
    )
    object_name : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items = object_list_callback,
        name = 'Object Name'
    )
```

However, I want to have a default value of the `file_path`, which I would be using most of the time, so I don't have to type it. But then the `file_path_update` doesn't get called and hence the object list (`scene.my_object_list`) doesn't get updated.

So my question is the following. Is there a way to call the update function (in this example, the `file_path_update`) when initializing a custom property? Alternatively, what else could I do in this situation?

Comment: Been my experience that an items callback can be a bottleneck too.   Be tempted to use something akin to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211247/cant-find-update-callback-for-collectionproperty/211290#211290   As for hardcoding a default filepath, unless its relative to the addon or some blender path its going to be NADA like windows path above on my linux machine. Having an option to set a folder containing libraries in addon  prefs could be an option.